# Aws Route 53 with hostinger domain connected to EC2 instance for Restful API

Tags: amazon-ec2, hosting, amazon-route53, restful-url

I manage to success run the frontend using the domain in hostinger using AWS Route 53 then connect to the EC2 instance.
Then i created other EC2 instance for backend then use another domain from hostinger then connect to AWS Route 53 but its not working. I already check the DNS checker online is already been setup an suppose to work.
Is there some i missed for the backed Restful api set up?

Answer (score -1):

Kindly disregard this question , its already working, i missed the port when checking the api is it suppose to be like this domain:8282. But i dont like it, i want to remove the port